# C - ERROR not defined and storage unknown

Tags: c, dev-c++

I have this code for deleting directories. I have `header1.h`, `header1.c`, `main.c`.
I get some errors, but the one is more difficult to me to understand is the errors: 
(1) storage size of `ffblk` isn't known.
Also, i have the doubt of how to define the attributes of `ffblk`, which are ff_name and `ff_attrib`
This example is from various code examples from the internet(even other from here), all of them do the same code, just in my case it does not work.
Am i missing the definition of the struct? or maybe i have added code where it should not be any code?
Could you please help me? I dont usually program in C. and i am using **Dev-Cpp**.

header1.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER1_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct ffblk ffblk;

#endif
```

header.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header1.h"
struct ffblk
{
    char ff_attrib[20];  //this line i added just so dont show error of unknown
    char ff_name[20];  //this line i added just so dont show error of unknown
};
```

main.c:

```
#ifndef FA_RDONLY
  #define FA_RDONLY _A_RDONLY
 #endif

#ifndef FA_HIDDEN
  #define FA_HIDDEN _A_HIDDEN
 #endif

 #ifndef FA_SYSTEM
  #define FA_SYSTEM _A_SYSTEM
 #endif

 #ifndef FA_DIREC
  #define FA_DIREC _A_SUBDIR
 #endif

 #ifndef FA_ARCH
  #define FA_ARCH _A_ARCH
 #endif


# include <stdio.h>
# include <dos.h>
# include <dir.h>
# include <io.h>
# include <conio.h>
#include "header1.h"

    typedef struct ffblk ffblk;

int BorrarArchivo(char *nombarch)
{
   printf("Borrando Archivo %s \n",nombarch);

   remove(nombarch);

   return 0;
}

int EliminarAtributo(char *nombarch,int atributo)
{
   printf("Elimina Atributo %s   %d\n",nombarch,atributo);

   chmod(nombarch,atributo);

   return 0;
}

int BorrarArbol(void)
{  
   struct ffblk ffblk;
   int done,err;

   err=0;
   done=findfirst("*.*",&ffblk,FA_RDONLY|FA_HIDDEN|FA_DIREC|FA_ARCH|FA_SYSTEM);

   while (!done)
   {
     if (FA_HIDDEN & ffblk.ff_attrib)
         EliminarAtributo(ffblk.ff_name,FA_HIDDEN);

     if (FA_SYSTEM & ffblk.ff_attrib)
         EliminarAtributo(ffblk.ff_name,FA_SYSTEM);

     if (FA_RDONLY & ffblk.ff_attrib)
         EliminarAtributo(ffblk.ff_name,FA_RDONLY);

     if (FA_ARCH & ffblk.ff_attrib)
         err=BorrarArchivo(ffblk.ff_name);
     else if (FA_DIREC & ffblk.ff_attrib)
     {
        if (ffblk.ff_name[0]!='.')
        { 
            chdir(ffblk.ff_name);

            err=BorrarArbol();

            chdir("..");

            if (!err)  
                printf("Removiendo %s\n",ffblk.ff_name);

            rmdir(ffblk.ff_name);
        }
     }
     else
        err=BorrarArchivo(ffblk.ff_name);

     if (err)
     {  
        printf("Error en el borrado ... !"); return err;
     }

     done=findnext(&ffblk);
    }

   return 0;
}

int main (void)
{ int err=0;
  char c;
    printf("Esta seguro  [ Si -> S , No ->otra tecla ] =>");
    c=getchar();
    if (!(c=='S' || c=='s')) return 0;
    err=BorrarArbol();
    if (err) printf("Error en el borrado ... !");
    return err;
}
```

EDIT:
I found a definition of struct and paste it in header.h

```
typedef struct ffblk {
      char lfn_magic[6];        /* LFN: the magic "LFN32" signature */
      short lfn_handle;     /* LFN: the handle used by findfirst/findnext */
      unsigned short lfn_ctime; /* LFN: file creation time */
      unsigned short lfn_cdate; /* LFN: file creation date */
      unsigned short lfn_atime; /* LFN: file last access time (usually 0) */
      unsigned short lfn_adate; /* LFN: file last access date */
      char ff_reserved[5];      /* used to hold the state of the search */
      unsigned char ff_attrib;  /* actual attributes of the file found */
      unsigned short ff_ftime;  /* hours:5, minutes:6, (seconds/2):5 */
      unsigned short ff_fdate;  /* (year-1980):7, month:4, day:5 */
      unsigned long ff_fsize;   /* size of file */
      char ff_name[260];        /* name of file as ASCIIZ string */
    }ffblk;
```

now it shows error:

```
C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc89P309.o:Untitled3.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `findfirst'
C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc89P309.o:Untitled3.c:(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `findnext'
```

Comment: In what line of your code does that error appear?

Comment: Also, does it appear once you've added the definition of `struct ffblk` in header.c?

Comment: Initially the code was just the main.c but i get multiple errors, and seeing the examples i created the header.h and header.c  The laste error remaining appears at the main.c at the declaration of struct ffblk ffblk.

Comment: I just noticed you're using some Windows-specific file, so I probably can't help you too much, but your new error usually means that findfirst and findnext need to be defined, included, or linked. Do you know what file they're supposed to come from? If you include the dos library (`#include <dos.h>`) then do you also have to link to the dos library (`-ldos` from the command line, not sure what to do in Dev-Cpp).

Comment: It's been many years since I worked in c but doesn't main.c need a main routine as in int main() { <your code> }?

Comment: I tried to define them with: #define findfirst(n,a,b) (_dos_findfirst((n),(b),(a)))
 #define findnext(b) (_dos_findnext(b)) . But shows errors: C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccilDOws.o:Untitled6.c:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `_dos_findfirst'
C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccilDOws.o:Untitled6.c:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `_dos_findnext'

Comment: @SandraG. I think you will have to define them as C functions, unless `_dos_findfirst` and `_dos_findnext` appear somewhere in the DOS library (in which case you'd need to link to them).

Comment: @LAS her `main.c` file does in fact have a function declared as `int main(void) { ... }`

Comment: @SandraG. By "define them" I mean that you need to write a loop that goes through the file, finds the first instance of the `ffblk` you're trying to find. Seems to me there's no need to write two separate functions for `findfirst` and `findnext`; just write one function `findnext` and use that for both cases.

I don't **know** that that's the case, but it's all I can think of at the moment, because I'm not familiar with the Window dos library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the problem was always the functions findfirst(a,b,c) and findnext(a,b,c). I had to change the functions and use their version with 2 parameters and not 3.  I put all the code in one file with the includes, typedef struct and the code below.